# owerflow:hiden with border-radius on mobile browser

Tags: android, html, css

How do I create a mask `div` with `border-radius` in an Android browser?

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:300px;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    position:relative;
    width:240px;
    height:120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    background:#123456;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.item {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background:#654321;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SVjjb/

In iOS it works correctly.

Comment: Android browser ignore overflow hidden with border radius

Answer (score 0):

It simply isn't supported on android devices.

You can try the following:

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/8PL2A/1/) this not woking in mobile (HTC Wildfire S) box has round border, item border but does not rounded border

Comment: Can you describe a bit more clear what isn't working?   As soon as I test this on my android browser it works. If you want to give the corners of your item div a radius, you have to apply the above code on that div.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it is not possible at this time. Seems to be a bug in the stock android browser. Only way to do this at this time is using images and photoshop.